# Composite UI Application for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, cab, scsf

Do we have Composite UI Application equivalent for asp.net MVC?
Can SCSF be used with ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 0):

LightSwitch is one more and new

Comment: and MVC is a architecture you can use SharePoint to Develop Application too.